# Python relpath /home/<username> vs. ~

Tags: python

In Python3.4 (and also 2.6), using the os.path.relpath cmd, I get different answers if I run:
`os.path.relpath("~/foo/bar.txt", "~")`
than if I run
`os.path.relpath("~/foo/bar.txt", "/home/<username>/")`
(where I replace `<username>` with my user name, naturally!)

Namely, if I'm in my home directory, in the first case I get
    `foo/bar.txt`
(as I would expect), but in the second case I get
    `~/foo/bar.txt`
which is not what I would expect, given that ~ is exactly `/home/<username>`.  (I get the same result in the second case regardless of whether I include the trailing '/' in the second arg.)

The second case gives an even more bizarre result if I run this within a subdirectory of my home directory, say ~/Data/:
    `Data/~/foo/bar.txt`
which unless I'm mistaken is a non-existent directory.

I can figure out a work-around for this, but what is the logic for why it's happening this way?  I don't suppose it's a bug, since it's been around a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~` isn’t actually always your home directory—that’s only your shell’s interpretation. You can create a directory named `~` anywhere you want, just as you could create a directory named `orange`. Since `~` could be a plain old directory name, Python is treating it that way.

If you want Python to interpret `~` as meaning the home directory, as a shell would do, you need to tell Python you want to replace `~` with the path to the home directory using [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) before passing your directory names to `relpath`.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my "even more bizarre result" question; I guess it's not so bizarre after all.

Comment: (Nuts, tried to edit that, but I was too slow.)  But I'm really trying to get a relative path from my home dir, and "~" is actually giving me the answer I was expecting.  So why doesn't it give me a path relative to my home dir if I give it the /home/<username> as the second arg?  Why does Python stick in the "~"?  That doesn't seem to be a relative path.  (Or putting it differently, how do I get a relpath to a file from my home directory?)

Comment: @MikeMaxwell: If it looks like Python is sticking in a `~`, that means there was a `~` in one of your inputs. `expandhome` on the inputs before passing to `relpath` should replace that for you. Also, running the inputs through `abspath` after `expandhome` and before `relpath` might help.